# How to do user authentication using a mysql databse

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

On a website:
After a successful login, how to stop sending the user to localhost/login cause he's already logged in, but send him instead to a localhost/index where there's a logout button.

Video reference (min 00:48)
https://youtu.be/DcB1Ge0HQ4I

Comment: before issuing the redirection, check the credentials and react accordingly.

Comment: could you add more information about the implementation please?

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple task ,,,did you create $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;